c++ multithreaded program exit code 139
I tried to implement a simple thread pool using C++. My cloud server has 2 cores. When I set the number of thread pool threads to more than 2, the program cannot exit normally and the exit code is 139. How should I modify it? ? Below is my code：
#ifndef THREADPOOL__THREADPOOL_V1_H_
#define THREADPOOL__THREADPOOL_V1_H_

#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

class threadPool_v1 {
 public:
  threadPool_v1(int threads_num):stop(false), threads_num(threads_num){

  }

  ~threadPool_v1() = default;


  threadPool_v1(const threadPool_v1&) = delete;
  threadPool_v1(threadPool_v1&&) = delete;

  threadPool_v1& operator=(const threadPool_v1&) = delete;
  threadPool_v1& operator=(threadPool_v1&&) = delete;


  void init() {
    threads.reserve(threads_num);
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; i++) {
      threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(&threadPool_v1::run, this));
    }
  }

  void shutdown() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    stop = true;
    lock.unlock();
    cond.notify_all();
  }

  bool addTask(std::function<void()> fun) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    if(stop) {
      return false;
    }
    tasks.push(fun);
    cond.notify_one();
    return true;
  }

  void run() {
    while(!stop) {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
      if(tasks.empty()) {
        cond.wait(lock);
      }
      auto task = std::move(tasks.front());
      tasks.pop();
      lock.unlock();
      if(task) {
        task();
      }
    }
  }


 private:
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::condition_variable cond;
  bool stop;
  int threads_num;
  std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};

#endif//THREADPOOL__THREADPOOL_V1_H_

test code:
void printNum() {
  int num = random();
  std::cout << num << std::endl;
}


int main() {
  threadPool_v1 pool(4);
  std::function<void()> func = printNum;
  pool.init();
  pool.addTask(printNum);
  pool.addTask(printNum);
  pool.addTask(printNum);
  getchar();
  pool.shutdown();
}

My guess is that a thread accessed an empty queue, but I'm not sure why this error wouldn't be triggered if the number of threads is lower than the number of cores.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

threads.reserve(threads_num); for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; i++) { threads[i]= ... } You have undefined behavior right here. reserve() changes the capacity of the vector, but not its size. threads.size() is still zero, and threads[i] accesses an index out of bounds for any value i.

void run() { while(!stop) { This is a data race on stop variable. The fact that it's modified under the mutex doesn't help if you also access or modify it outside of the mutex.

if(tasks.empty()) { cond.wait(lock); } auto task = std::move(tasks.front()); The wait() could end for reasons other than an element being added to the queue (if nothing else, spurious wake-up is possible; but you also wake all threads after setting stop=true); so tasks may in fact be empty. You must check the condition after wait() returns, and loop back to wait if it's not satisfied. Or better still, use the wait() overload that takes a predicate - it does the correct looping for you.

Side note: names that contain two consecutive underscores (THREADPOOL__THREADPOOL_V1_H_) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.
